# Simultaneous dynamic async calls

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I have a dynamic list of strings including codes. 
I want to fetch events for each code and then yield to next state.

I have tried `Future.wait()` but since is dynamic I can not pass a list of async calls.

This is my code so far:

```
var packagesData = List<BuiltList<Event>>();
for (var packageNumber in packages) {
  final packageEvents = await serviceDataSource.fetchPackageEvents(packageNumber);
  packagesData.add(packageEvents);

  if (packagesData.length == packages.length) {
    return persistAllPackagesData(packagesData);
  }
}
```

I wanted to do something similar to a Promise:

```
Promise.all([
   // for loop here
]).then(() => {
   console.log('I did everything!');
});
```

Comment: I don't get why `Future.wait` does not works for you, can you clarify ?

Comment: Another comment, on `Promise.all` where you put *for loop here*, you can no set a for loop there, Promise.all will do the looping automatically for you. Maybe if you show me what you've done with `Future.wait` I can help you better.

Comment: Could you post the entire method of the code you provided? And also the implementation of persistAllPackagesData()?

Comment: @PabloBarrera my persistAllPackagesData function only saves data locally.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a taskList to maintain needed task and use Future.wait

```
List<Future<int>> taskList = [];
taskList.add(getRandomNumber()); 
...
Future.wait(taskList)
    .then
```

full code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

Future<int> getRandomNumber() async {
  var random = new Random();
  return random.nextInt(100);
}

void findSmallestNumberInList(List<int> lst) {
  print("all numbers are in:");
  lst.forEach((l) => print(l));
  lst.sort();
  int largest = lst.first;
  print("The smallest random # we generated was: ${largest}");
}

void main() async {

  List<Future<int>> taskList = [];

  taskList.add(getRandomNumber());
  taskList.add(getRandomNumber());
  taskList.add(getRandomNumber());

  Future.wait(taskList)
    .then((List<int> results) => findSmallestNumberInList(results));

  Future.wait([getRandomNumber(), getRandomNumber(), getRandomNumber()])
    .then((List<int> results) => findSmallestNumberInList(results));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice approach, but the way he is doing it should work too, right? I think he is just doing something wrong inside persistAllPackagesData()

Comment: It's not easy without the detail of persistAllPackagesData(). the best I can do is provide possible solution. thanks.

Comment: My persistAllPackagesData() only saves data locally and return it. I tried you approach but when I add the function to the aux list, the function is being called.